# Simple geometric progression question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question is probably on a way lower level than things usually asked here, but while I was studying for a test I stumbled upon this and can't figure it out.

The sum of the first and second terms of a geometric progression is -3, the sum of the fifth and sixth terms is -3/16. Find the sum of the first 8 terms.

I tried writing out the terms as a, ar, ar^2 and making some proportions and what not but I'm always stuck with 2 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $a,r$ are the first term and the common ratio respectively,

$$a+ar=-3, ar^4+ar^5=-\frac3{16}$$

$$a(1+r)=-3\ \ \ \ (1)\text{ and } ar^4(1+r)=-\frac3{16}\ \  \ \ (2)$$

Divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ as $1+r\ne0$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=ar^{n-1}$ where $a=a_1$ and $r$ is the common ratio.

Then, 
$$a_1+a_2=-3\Rightarrow a(1+r)=-3.$$
$$a_5+a_6=-3/16\Rightarrow ar^4(1+r)=-3/16.$$

Now 
$$\frac{ar^4(1+r)}{a(1+r)}=\frac{-3/16}{-3}\Rightarrow r^4=(1/2)^4\Rightarrow r=1/2.$$

Hence, you'll have$$a=\frac{-3}{1+r}=-2.$$

Also, you can use
$$a+ar+\cdots+ar^{n}=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}.$$
Note that your case is $n=7$ (not $n=8$).